# React component was not re-rendered and updated after redux store change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**Sandbox Link to reproduce this issue:** https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-component-store-issue-kegqo

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sandbox Link issue fixed:** https://codesandbox.io/s/fix-redux-component-store-issue-j7oxb?file=/src/redux/reducers/userReducer.js

```
const userReducer = (state=initialState, actions) => {
    switch(actions.type) {
        case UPDATE_USERS:
            return {...state, users: [...actions.payload.users]}
        default:
            return {...state}
    }
}
```

[image]

In the react reducer, **for array use** [...Array], **for the object** use {...object}